# Is there a better way than cp to copy millions of files while preserving hard links?

Tags: cp, file-copy, hard-link

So in [this story](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2014-08/msg00012.html) on the GNU coreutils ML, someone used cp to copy 430 million files and needed to preserve hard links, and *just barely* got it to finish after 10 days.

The big problem was that, in order to preserve hard links, cp has to keep a hashtable of already copied files, which took up 17GB of memory towards the end and had the system thrashing on swap.

Is there some utility that would have handled the task better?

Comment: `rsync` has done very much optimizations, so it might be a good option to try. Perhaps `cpio` could work too. I think the trick must be to do it in portions, perhaps even in parallel, if you want max speed.

Comment: @MattBianco: the problem is that you can't preserve hard links if you do it in portions unless you repeat a lot of work.

Comment: Based on reading that thread, it seems they have made some fixes to the code. Does that not help? Have you tested the cp with the new fixes?

Comment: Hrrm. Maybe the [tar trick](http://meinit.nl/using-tar-and-ssh-to-efficiently-copy-files-preserving-permissions)? I don't know if/how that handles hardlinks, though.

Comment: Files with only 1 link could be done in portions. Finding those is cheap. Are the majority of the files "duplicates"? I think the best approach could be different depending on circumstances like the structure of the data, as well as of course which filesystem the files reside on.

Comment: @MattBianco: in that particular case, most files were indeed multiple duplicates, as the device was used to do backups via rsync.

Comment: `cpio` and filesystem-aware tools like `ufsdump` are the only candidates I can think of that handle hard links properly (by inode number). Gnu `tar` seems to have some kind of support for hard links, but I doubt it can avoid the problem that `cp -r` has with memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

If the `tar` or `rsync` solutions fails and if the directory is the root of a filesystem  you can use the old `dump/restore` backup utilities (yes that stills works).

`dump` duplicates the filesystem characteristics without going through the kernel filesystem interface so it is quite fast.

The inconvenient is that `dump` is sensible to  modifications made on the source file system while copying. 
So better  umount the filesystem  or remount it read only or stop any application that could access it before starting a copy. If you respect that condition the copy is reliable.

Depending on the filesystem type the `dump` command name can change, for instance, you can have the `xfsdump` for the XFS.

The following command is similar to the `tar` example :

```
dump 0uf - /dev/sdaX  | (cd /target && restore rf -)
```

The number is the incremental copy level; `0` indicates to do a full copy.

Comment: Let's just add, that `dump` is extX only, but similar utilities exist for other filesystems.

Comment: @peterph Yes you are right that depends on the operating system too.

Answer (score 0):

I recall rsync resulted in some problems for me; I am not sure if these were hard links or device files or whatever. Since then I use

```
tar -cv $(ls) | ( cd /mnt; tar xv )
```

which will copy all files from . to /mnt. My whole story can be found here: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Cloning#file-by-file_copy_2

Comment: Is this able to handle hardlinks?

Comment: @evilsoup see my comment on the question, the one beginning with `cpio`. Gnu tar can recreate hard links somehow, but I doubt that it can do it effectively on the kind of volumes mentioned in the question. I guess someone has to try it...

Comment: GNU tar without `-f` defaults to stdin/stdout. Others may not do so. Some default to tape devices. I recommend using `tar cf - $(ls) | (cd /mnt && tar xf -)`. Replacing `;` in the subshell with `&&` protects you from `cd` typos. Skipping `v` saves you from `tar`s that are verbose on stdout.